# Magento with Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, magento, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular

I want to build Magento store with Angular-Js for that I have read so many article on net and check stack overflow questions but I am not getting up to the mark answer so I decided to ask with my own problem.

For ex: I want to use Angular-Js in Magento for list page(category page) for that what I need to change and where?In which file I need to add angular controller , model , route and all stuff related angular? If any one is there who has used Angular with Magento before please help me to clear my problem.

I think we need to change core Magento controller files may be but not sure.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this about AngularJS or Angular2?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Right now I am using Angular-Js but I don't mind if you give me solution related Angular 2.

Comment: You can't simply add AngularJS into the source files of Magento, you should create a stand alone Web Application using AngularJS and then use Magento as a REST interface to manage the products, categories, promotions, ect... Check this out, it may make things clearer: http://netzarbeiter.com/media/mm14es/magento-and-angularjs/#/3

Comment: @lain I have checked this link before but I don't think this link is useful in my case because I don't want to build Application. I want to use Angular-Js in front-end (Magento website). for that I need to add "ng-app" controller in 1column.phtml file then "ng-controller" in list.phtml file after that I need to add model and route for this ng-controller and so on...